# SQL where both conditions in brackets are true

Tags: sql, brackets, multiple-conditions

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE
    Column1 = 'X'
    AND Column2 = 'Y'
    AND (Column3 != 'D' AND Column4 != 'D') -- Want to apply this filter ONLY if both conditions are true
```

How to write third filter so that it's applied only if both of them are true. Currently, brackets make no difference but I need expression in brackets to be considered as a single condition

Example:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
X           Y           D           L   
X           Y           L           L   
X           Y           L           D   
X           Y           D           D   -- want to remove this line
```

Result should be:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
X           Y           D           L   
X           Y           L           L   
X           Y           L           D
```

Comment: You're done already.

Comment: You just remove AND (Column3 != 'D' AND Column4 != 'D')...

Comment: check update so you'll see what's the issue

Comment: I see, then what you did is already true. and the brackets really doesn't matter.

Comment: yep, that's what it says in my question :)

Comment: Your expected result is wrong or your codition. [This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/881f1/1/0) is the result with your coditions. I guess you want `Column3 != 'D' OR Column4 != 'D'` instead of `Column3 != 'D' AND Column4 != 'D'`.

Comment: By the way, as your where clause is all AND, so have or haven't brackets really doesn't matter. The brackets is importance if the where clause contains mix of AND and OR.

Comment: Oh, I overlook it. @TimS is right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE
    Column1 = 'X'
    AND Column2 = 'Y'
    AND NOT (Column3 = 'D' AND Column4 = 'D')
```

Comment: How does this include rows where Column1<>'X' or Column2 <> 'Y'?

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @ile: But this is not the query you've asked for. You wanted to apply the third condition only if the first two are already true. That means you want also records where `Column1 <> 'X'` or `Column2 <> 'Y'`. This query [doesn't take it into account](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f2e3/1/0)(last two rows are not included). So either it's wrong or your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess my question is not formed very well. "only if both of them are true" refers to expression in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `OR`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    (Column1 <> 'X' OR Column2 <> 'Y')
OR
    (Column1 = 'X' AND Column2 = 'Y' AND (Column3 != 'D' AND Column4 != 'D'))
```

Side-note: your expected result is wrong or your codition. [This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/881f1/1/0) is the result with your coditions. I guess you want `Column3 != 'D' OR Column4 != 'D'` instead of `Column3 != 'D' AND Column4 != 'D'`.

Then this is more appropriate and returns your expected result:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    (Column1 <> 'X' OR Column2 <> 'Y')
OR
    (Column1 = 'X' AND Column2 = 'Y' AND (Column3 != 'D' OR Column4 != 'D'))
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/881f1/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do it this way... problem is that my real-world query has a huge list of filters so I'd have to repeat them in both clauses

Comment: Actually not sure that this will work because my list of other filters is very big so I'd have to repeat all of them

Comment: No, my expected result is good but query needs to be rewritten so that it returns following results